# Select the first element of a class 'x' after a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

I've got some code like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum<a href=# class="a">link</a><span class="b">Text</span>More lorem ipsum<a href=# class="a">link</a><span class="b">Text 2</span>
```

And I'd like to let users click the `link` and be able to do something with the span (make it flash, hide it, whatever). I'm using jQuery, and this is what I've got so far:

```
$('.a').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.a').css('background-color', 'red');
 });
```

This works as long as I'm diligent about having links before the spans, and no other code in the text. However, I'm not happy with it, and there must be a better way. I've also tried:

```
$('.a').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.b').css('background-color', 'red');
 });
```

But that selects all of the spans of class `b`, so no good.

I'm new and at a loss. I seek wisdom.

Comment: Your second snippet (`$(this).next('.b').css('background-color', 'red');`) should return only **one** sibling, not all `span`s.

Comment: Yep, don't know what I was doing before. Maybe it was a 'fixed in transcription' correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a.a').click(function() {
    $(this).next('span.b').css('background-color', 'red');
 });
```

should work fine for you. It gets the immediately following sibling.

Comment: Indeed, it does just that. Not sure why I was having so much trouble with it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this?

```
$(".a").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("something_special");
    $(".something_special + .b").css({backgroundColor: "red"});
    $(this).removeClass("something_special");
});
```